# Invalid provisioning profile when submitting WatchKit extension?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am trying to submit our app with a WatchKit extension now that Apple is allowing 3rd party developers to do so. However everytime we try to submit through Application Loader we are greeted with the following error message:

> Invalid provisioning profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle bundleidentifier.watchkitapp is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate.] For more information, visit the developer portal.

We have set up the provisioning profile just like we have done before without any problems. We have App ID's for bundleidntifier (Companion app), bundleidntifier.watchkitextension (WatchKit extension) and bundleidntifier. bundleidentifier.watchkitapp (WatchKit app) with corresponding distribution provision profiles.

We think the problem lies in the WatchKit app target. In Xcode there is no Build Settings tab when the WatchKit app target is selected thus we cannot assign the provision profile we created.

We have also tried using a WildCard ID and Provision profile with the same error being generated. Where are we going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Following steps help me out: 1.Make sure "App Groups" in Capabilities page in Container target and Extension target.

2.Goto Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > YOUR_ACCOUNT > View Details ..., CTRL+Click one of the Profiles and open in Finder. Move all Profiles to Trash.

3.Open "App Groups" in Container target and Extension target. Xcode will generate two profiles for you, just like iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: YOURAPPID and iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: YOURAPPID.watchkitextension. (Make sure your container target and WatchKit App target choose the first one as PP,and your extension target choose the second one).

4.Maybe you need to regenerate your "Distribution Profile" in Developer Member Center.

5.If everything goes well, you can do whatever build, run and submit.

Answer (score 0):

We managed to fix it by setting the code signing settings at the project level instead of the target level.

Comment: When you say you fixed it by setting the code singing settings at project level, which code signing profile did you use at the project level? Everything I tried won't work.

Comment: We set our provisioning profile at the project level by selecting the project xcodeproj and editing the Build Settings with automatic code signing identities. We then set provisioning specific provisioning profiles for our app, extensions and tests (all with automatic code signing identities). Once this was set we could build our IPA without any code signing issues.

Comment: Did you make a distribution profile for the watchkit app target (com.companyname.appname.watchkitapp)? And if so, where do you use it, because like you said, there is no Build Settings tab when the WatchKit app target is selected?

Comment: Fyi, this is no longer an issue for me with Xcode 6.3, there is a Build Settings tab for the WatchKit App target now (where there wasn't in 6.2).